# Ethernet compatibility

Tags: ethernet, layer2, osi

I am improving my knowledge about the Ethernet protocol. During my study, I noticed that they are multiple versions of the protocol. Example: 2.5GBASE-T and 5GBASE-T and 100BASE-TX.
I wonder depending on the wire that we connect the NIC will use the good version? Or the versions are retro-compatible?

Many thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are roughly 100 Ethernet variants, see [Wikipedia:Ethernet physical layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer) for an updated list.

2.5GBASE-T and 5GBASE-T are somewhat special in that "Smartrate" ports actually train the cable at hand and use the best possible speed. All other variants use simpler Auto Negotiation where each side advertises the variants it supports and the best mutual one is used to link. If the cable is insufficient the link fails or performs badly.

Many ports are downward compatible to lower speeds (via Auto Negotiation), especially for the most common twisted-pair variants, although this is purely optional. For instance, nearly all 1000BASE-T ports also support 100BASE-TX and 10BASE-T, or most 10GBASE-T ports support 1000BASE-T as well. Fiber ports aren't usually downward compatible, but it's possible if their wavelengths match, e.g. 10GBASE-SR and 1000BASE-SX.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Ethernet has a wide variety of physical layer specifications, targeting different speeds, media types and technology levels.

Many of those specifications are short-lived dead ends and if you operate on the bleeding edge, you risk getting stuck with something that is difficult to connect to more modern equipment. Generally by the time the technology trickles down to more regular businesses though it has settled on a relative handful of standards for each speed.

BASE-T Ethernet handles backwards compatibility through supporting multiple standards on the same port and having an auto-negotiation process. A port whose highest supported standard is 100BASE-TX will normally* also support 10BASE-T. A port whose highest supported standard is 1000BASE-T will normally also support 100BASE-TX and 10BASE-T.

However for higher speed ports you have to read the documentation carefully. Early 10GBASE-T ports would only support 1000BASE-T and 10GBASE-T. Later ports added support for 100BASE-TX. Later still 2.5GBASE-T and 5GBASE-T came along and some but not all 10GBASE-T ports added support for them.

25GBASE-T and 40GBASE-T exist in theory, but I can't seem to find any evidence of actual products, so I can't look up what level of backwards compatibility they offer.

Traditionally Ethernet autonegotiation only took account of the capabilities of the end devices, not the cable in between so if the cable is not up to the requirements of the highest speed supported by the devices you may get a link that is unreliable or does not work at all. Some vendors have added their own extensions to work around this and I believe such may have been included in the 2.5G/5Gbase-T standards though i'm not sure on the details.

Fiber Ethernet has settled on modular transceivers as the solution to handling the wider variety of physical layer standards. Initially there was a wide varity of different module standards, but in recent years the world has settled on the "SFP" and "QSFP" families of module standards. The difference is that the "SFP" family provides a single lane of data, while the QSFP family provides four lanes of data, so it can offer 4 times the speed at a given technology level. My understaning is that within the SFP or QSFP families it is generally possible to fit slower transceivers in faster slots, providing for a level of backwards compatibility.

Unfortunately many vendors vendor-lock their SFP slots, this in turn has lead to third party transceiver vendors creating clone transceivers which can be programmed to claim to be transceivers from whatever vendor the user requires.

For high speed short distance links, rather than using a pair of transcievers and a fiber between them it is possible to use "direct attatch cables" that plug directly into the transceiver slots. Over very short distances these may be passive copper cables, for slightly longer links they are likely to be fiber based.

* The main exception to this is copper to fiber media converters, these normally only support a single speed.